# How to save Geolocation information in a text format based on date month and year

Tags: javascript, php

I'm on the process of saving, user geolocation information "latitude and longitude" in a text log file.

I need to save this log file based on day and month (filename).

Example :

```
 <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        lati = position.coords.latitude;
        longi = position.coords.longitude;

        console.log(lati);
        console.log(longi);
    }
    </script>
```

Now I have to log the output as a text file.

output log file >>  filename_month_date_year.txt

So it won't overwrite the same file name, again and again, it will keep the record of all those geolocation in my directory where I save it.

Comment: Ok so date processing in PHP is fairly straight forward. What have you tried

Comment: I'm trying it with javascript for now, but if there is a way in php then help me out to save the coordinates information in a log file. But keep in mind, i need the log information file name with a unique name to avoid overwriting.

Comment: Why don't you try something and share your code, and we can help you from there.

Comment: Javascript, Ok but how are you going to get the filename and the data to PHP and the web server where I assume the file will be stored? Also remember anything you do in javascript on the client PC cna get messed with by the user

Comment: Am gonna use this method now : https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

It shows the exact latitude and longitude of the user if they allow permission to share their location through the browser. Once they do it, the server will log their information on the server side as a log file, so we can later take a look at it.

Comment: You would just do an xhr request containing the data and post it back to your server where it is appended to the log file?

Comment: explain me in brief @mblaettermann

Comment: I just did. You want me to post a fully working code example it seems. Try to ask a concrete question where you are stuck.

Comment: Do you know what an ajax/xhr request is?

Comment: @mblaettermann alright edited my question now. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: No, it isnt. There is no code sending data to the server. You just log it into the browsers console

Comment: @mblaettermann i used the console log method to understand is the code is working or not. Yes, i'm looking for the code which sends information to server and then i can log it as a text file. That's the help am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update answer with an updated question.

Change some code in the showposition function. please check below code.

```
  function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        lati = position.coords.latitude;
        longi = position.coords.longitude;

        var location=lati+','+longi;

        console.log(lati);
        console.log(longi);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "savelog.php?q="+location, true);
        xhttp.send(); 
    }
```

PHP code in savelog.php file.

```
<?php 
    $location=$_REQUEST['q'];
    $destinationPath="YOUR DESTINATION PATH TO STORE LOG";
    $currenttime="CURRENT DATE FORMAT WHICH YOU WANT";
    file_put_contents($destinationPath . $currenttime . '.txt', print_r($location, true), FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: I think there is a better way than this by using "getCurrentPosition()"

Comment: Yes, that also we can use if we wanted but i was using paid service for this so i was suggested that.

Comment: His main concern is to store location. so thought he has alredy lat-long of user. so suggesti method to store it.

Comment: I think, my question is to log the geolocation information. Not the IP information.

Comment: So there is an answer to store log via PHP on daily basis. question is to store log not to find geo location.

Comment: ... and how to get the data into the php script via xhr

Comment: I had update my answer. as per the updated question.

Comment: @YagnikDetroja Well am getting this error.  https://i.imgur.com/Pih2zjM.png

Comment: @josep Sorry, I am forgotten to define xhttp. but you already updated my answer thanks.